# React review form not submitting review on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to preface this that I am learning JavaScript and React so this is all very new to me.

I am building a "simple" movie rating app and need to be able to push a review to a div "on submit" and cannot figure out how to do so. I have tried using update state in react and/or creating functions to try to accomplish this and cannot figure out how to do this for the life of me. I did somewhat succeed using the latter method, but was getting errors about using unique key props. The other problem was I am to use a star-rating component and when I submitted the review, it wasn't pushing that to the div. This is where I'm at currently:

````
import { Button, Form, Input } from "reactstrap";
import Stars from "./stars";


export default function ReviewForm() {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState("");
  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    setReviews(e.target.value);
  };
  const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    console.log("Form Submitted");
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <Stars />
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Input
          className="form-control" type="text"
          placeholder="Enter you review"
          value={reviews}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <br></br>
        <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

// This is what I have in my Stars component:

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaStar} from 'react-icons/fa'

const Stars = () => {
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);
    return(
        <div>
            {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
                const ratingValue = i + 1;
                return <label>
                    <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="rating" 
                    value={ratingValue} 
                    onClick={() => setRating(ratingValue)}
                    />
                    <FaStar 
                    className="star" 
                    color={ratingValue <= (hover || rating) ? "gold" : "lightgray"} 
                    size={20}
                    onMouseEnter={() => setHover(ratingValue)}
                    onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
                    />
                    </label>;
            })}
            <p>I rate this movie {rating + " stars"}</p>
        </div>
        );
};

export default Stars```
````

Comment: Can you share also your other components like Star and Input component? Or even better if you can create an example with codesandbox then we can help you better

Comment: I edited my previous post to include the Stars component. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working version of your code. You should use `key` in your `map` and `e.preventDefault()` in your form submit function. As final touch you should set another `state` inside your form submit and show this value in a `div` or some html element. Also I see that you want to get child state into parent so you can call callback for this https://codesandbox.io/embed/brave-euler-ybp9cx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

ReviewForm.js

```
export default function ReviewForm() {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [star, setStar] = useState();
  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    setReviews(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValue(reviews + " with " + star + " star ");
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <Stars setStar={setStar} />
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter you review"
          value={reviews}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <br></br>
        <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <div>{value}</div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Stars.js

```
const Stars = ({ setStar }) => {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (ratingValue) => {
    setRating(ratingValue);
    setStar(ratingValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
        const ratingValue = i + 1;
        return (
          <label key={i}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="rating"
              value={ratingValue}
              onClick={() => handleClick(ratingValue)}
            />
            <FaStar
              className="star"
              color={ratingValue <= (hover || rating) ? "gold" : "lightgray"}
              size={20}
              onMouseEnter={() => setHover(ratingValue)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
            />
          </label>
        );
      })}
      <p>I rate this movie {rating + " stars"}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Stars;
```

Comment: You are a genius, this worked! I modified it a bit and added a name input and got it to populate as well. It is creating a div below the input fields. The only thing I still can't seem to get is the stars populating with the review, even with the code you provided?

Comment: Check my edit please, it should work as you want now @DavidFeudale

Answer (score 1):

You probably are seeing a page refresh when you press the submit button. This is the default behavior of HTML forms.

When using React or any front-end framework, you'd want to handle the form submission yourself rather than letting the browser submit your forms.

In your `onSubmit` function, add the following line
`e.preventDefult()`

```
const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log("Form Submitted");
};
```

Your code will work perfectly.

Comment: I was able to get the page to stop refreshing as you called! I now get the print out to my console.log "Form submitted" but now I am stuck on how to actually push the review to the div - do I need to make a function for that?

Comment: the reviews variable you declared using useState is a reactive variable, meaning you can incorporate the value directly inside of any react JSX component. Eg `<div>{review}</div>` will do it perfectly.

Comment: As a matter of fact, if you just want to display the entered review to your page, you don't even need the onSubmit function. Generally, you'd use forms to submit data to a server using AJAX calls instead of the generic HTML form submissions.

Answer (score 1):

````
import { Button, Form, Input } from "reactstrap";
import Stars from "./stars";


export default function ReviewForm() {
  const [Reviews, setReviews] = useState("");
const [ReviewsRating, setReviewsRating] = useState(5);
const [Reviews_, setReviews_] = useState([]);
  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    setReviews(e.target.value);
  };
  const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault()
console.log("Form Submitted");
//After upload to the server
setReviews_([Reviews, ...Reviews_]
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <Stars getRating={getRating}/>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Input
          className="form-control" type="text"
          placeholder="Enter you review"
          value={reviews}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <br></br>
        <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
<div class="reviews">
 {Reviews_.map(item => <div> {item}</div> )}
</>


    </div>
  );
}```
````

Then to get the stars rating value use props like...
And make sure you call that property (function) inside your Starts component

```
const getRating =(value)=>{

setReviewsRating(value)
}
```